# Как оформить цитату в прямой речи?

Tags: прямая-речь

Книжный персонаж в диалоге с другим персонажем цитирует чью-либо фразу. Подскажите, как это оформить? 
Например:

– А она сказала: "Знаешь, лучше вам с другом больше ко мне не подходить".

Будет ли это правильным?

Answer (score 2):

Я называю такую конструкцию ***прямая речь внутри прямой речи*** — говорящий дословно произносит то, что сказал (возможно, совсем недавно) другой человек.

С пунктуацией у вас все нормально:
начальное тире соответствует оформлению диалога;
двоеточие вводит (показывает) чужое высказывание;
в кавычки заключено само высказывание (цитата);
в конце повествовательного предложения — после кавычек — стоит точка.

Для иллюстрации (и подтверждения-закрепления) приведу интересный пример, в котором есть диалоговая прямая речь: внутри нее — чужие слова (цитата) и несобственно-прямая речь, далее — слова автора, затем — продолжение прямой речи.

*Ее пальцы, повозившись с застежкой сумки, достали пачку фотографий.*
*— Муж мне пеняет: «Зачем ты это хранишь? Сожги». А я все думаю: может, на что-нибудь и сгодятся. Держите. — Она сунула фотографии Страйку; тот не стал отказываться. — Теперь пусть у вас хранятся. В Гейтсхед. Вот куда он поехал.*
[Р. Гэлбрейт. На службе зла](http://loveread.ec/read_book.php?id=53624&p=33)